# Wordpress does not sent email once a record is changed to a different domain

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have developed a WordPress website for one of my clients. Once the development was over i just kept the files and DB in the same location and only changed the domain name which is the live URL. When i did that the email is not working. I don't know what more to be added. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the SMTP configuration of your server.

Answer (score 0):

please check **writing Setting** (admin dashboar/setting/writing)

OR

Try [WP Mail SMTP by WPForms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin